# BigQuery Full outer join producing "left join" results

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 2 tables, both of which contain distinct id values.  Some of the id values might occur in both tables and some are unique to each table.  Table1 has 10,910 rows and Table2 has 11,304 rows

When running a left join query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.id)
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b on a.id = b.id
```

I get a total of 10,896 rows or 10,896 ids shared across both tables.

However, when I run a `FULL OUTER JOIN` on the 2 tables like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.id)
FROM table1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN EACH table2 b on a.id = b.id
```

I get total of 10,896 rows, but I was expecting all 10,910 rows from table1.

I am wondering if there is an issue with my query syntax.

Comment: have you tried #standardSQL as I suggested below?  - knowing result can help in further "troubleshooting"

Answer (score 9):

As you are using EACH - it looks like you are running your queries in Legacy SQL mode.
In BigQuery Legacy SQL - [COUNT(DISTINCT)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#countdistinct) function is probabilistic - gives statistical approximation and is not guaranteed to be exact.
You can use [EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#exact_count_distinct) function instead  - this one gives you exact number but a little more expensive on back-end

Even better option - just use [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)
For your specific query you will only need to remove `EACH` keyword and it should work as a charm

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.id)
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b on a.id = b.id
```

and

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.id)
FROM table1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 b on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: `SELECT EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(a.id) FROM table1 a FULL OUTER JOIN EACH table2 b on a.id = b.id` This returned 10,896 as well. I also tried just selecting the individual id column with no aggregation and still recieved 10,896 rows

Comment: Late to the game, but in your comment you say you are still using EACH.

Answer (score 1):

I added the original query as a subquery and counted ids and produced the expected results.  Still a little strange, but it works.

```
SELECT EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(a.id)
FROM
(SELECT a.id AS a.id,
b.id AS b.id
FROM table1 a FULL OUTER JOIN EACH table2 b on a.id = b.id))
```

Comment: this sounds like an issue/bug that you can report at https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/

Answer (score 1):

It is because you count in both case the number of non-null lines for table a by using a count(distinct a.id).
Use a count(*) and it should works.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add coalesce... BigQuery, unlike traditional SQL does not recognize fields unless used explicitly

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT coalesce(a.id,b.id))
FROM table1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN EACH table2 b on a.id = b.id

This query will now take full effect of full outer join :)