# LEFT JOIN IN BIG QUERY WITH DUPLICATES

Tags: google-bigquery

My tables have duplicate IDs, but I want to know which are the IDs that match between the two.
and which ones from table1 are not in table2.

Also ID in Table1 is INTEGER and in table2 is STRING, that's why I'm using cast

```
SELECT cast(T1.ID as STRING) as ID
FROM `project.dataset.table1` as T1 WHERE ID is not null
LEFT JOIN
SELECT DISTINCT(T2.ID) as ID
FROM `project.dataset.table2` as T2 WHERE ID is not null
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

I run the two queries separate and they are ok, but it shows this error when I try to create the left join

Big query Error:

```
Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword LEFT at [3:1]
```

I've tried from this questions [BigQuery Full outer join producing "left join" results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755073/bigquery-full-outer-join-producing-left-join-results)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T1.NPI)
FROM `project.dataset.table1` as T1 WHERE NPI is not null
JOIN `project.dataset.table2` as T2 WHERE NPI is not null
ON T1.NPI= T2.NPI
```

and just more errors.

Could you guide me please?

Comment: `WHERE ID is not null` would generally come after your `FROM` statements. I suspect that's why you see that error, `WHERE` should be at the end. I would also note that "duplicate IDs" in a table, and "null IDs" are a bad sign. An ID should probably be a primary key, which means it shouldn't be null and shouldn't be duplicated. I can't see your data so this might be an exceptional circumstance, but it's worth noting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [EXCEPT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#except) instead:

```
SELECT cast(T1.ID as STRING) as ID
FROM `project.dataset.table1` as T1 WHERE ID is not null
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT(T2.ID) as ID
FROM `project.dataset.table2` as T2 WHERE ID is not null
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didnt know the existance of EXCEPT